# puppeteer-sharp Failed to launch Base

Tags: windows, google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium, puppeteer-sharp

I have implemented it in my local and works well. But when I moved the changes to the window server it's giving the below error

Failed to launch Base! [0402/075840.212:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(70)] Failed to encrypt: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)\r\n[0402/075840.212:FATAL:headless_browser_main_parts.cc(103)] Check failed: OSCrypt::Init(local_state_.get()). \r\nBacktrace:\r\n\tIsSandboxedProcess [0x00007FFC31341842+705042]\r\n\tIsSandboxedProcess [0x00007FFC312C39A2+189298]\r\n\tIsSandboxedProcess [0x00007FFC312D2AF8+251080]\r\n\tIsSandboxedProcess [0x00007FFC312D39E0+254896]\r\n\tRelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded [0x00007FFC32B12123+12980755]\r\n\tRelaunchChromeBrowserWithNewCommandLineIfNeeded [0x00007FFC32B11E8D+12980093]\r\n\tovly_debug_event [0x00007FFC2F905929+16331561]\r\n\tovly_debug_event [0x00007FFC2FCC5B17+20264215]\r\n\tovly_debug_event [0x00007FFC2F904675+16326773]\r\n\tovly_debug_event [0x00007FFC2F9073BE+16338366]\r\n\tIsSandboxedProcess [0x00007FFC31DB7DB7+11675527]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC3125A837+8179991]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC3125B5AD+8183437]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC3125B20C+8182508]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC3125A1BD+8178333]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC3125A53A+8179226]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC31294D1A+8418810]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC31294BDC+8418492]\r\n\tCrashForExceptionInNonABICompliantCodeRange [0x00007FFC312949E7+8417991]\r\n\tChromeMain [0x00007FFC2E971238+408]\r\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00007FF6E8CF26B8+9912]\r\n\tOrdinal0 [0x00007FF6E8CF1A41+6721]\r\n\tGetHandleVerifier [0x00007FF6E8E3AF42+904642]\r\n\tBaseThreadInitThunk [0x00007FFC68F113F2+34]\r\n\tRtlUserThreadStart [0x00007FFC6AB054F4+52]\r\n\r\n

Can anyone please advise what should be the fix for the above error message?

Comment: Could you try using the Browser revision "851527"? It might be related to this https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/5197

Comment: I'm running into the same issue using Docker but don't quite see how to use Browser 851527 in docker

Answer (score 0):

We had the same error with default browser:
`Failed to launch browser! [0428/113352.960:ERROR:os_crypt_win.cc(70)] Failed to encrypt`

As @hardkoded suggested, using the revision `851527` we could launch the browser. Thank you!